# C# Firebase Admin SDK Push Notifications

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notifications to a mobile app, so I installed Firebase Admin SDK to my .Net project.
I followed the instructions on Firebase docs, but when I call the `SendAsync` from the SDK, it just hangs. Any idea why it would hang? Am I missing steps?

Here is my API code (Note this is only demo code to get it to work):

```
public async void SendPushNotification()
        {
            FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path to json file"),
            });

            var registrationToken = "fqCo_-tXKvY:APA91bGQ47Q2egnqn4Ml...";

            var message = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
            {
                Token = registrationToken,
            };

            string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);

            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        }
```

Comment: From where do I get that registration token?

Answer (score 5):

you have a deadlock because SendAsync will never finish.
if you are calling from ui thread you need to consider using **`ConfigureAwait(false)`** 
so your snippet will look like below:

```
public async void SendPushNotification()
    {
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path to json file"),
        });

        var registrationToken = "fqCo_-tXKvY:APA91bGQ47Q2egnqn4Ml...";

        var message = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
        {
            Token = registrationToken,
        };

        string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I never get to the success writeline.

Comment: have you set your registrationToken and credential file
p.s i have installed the following package ```https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/FirebaseAdmin``` version 1.13.0

Comment: From where do I get that registration token?

Comment: @pmh. the user submiting it to server, let me elaborate with request-respond scenario: at first client-device send register-request to firebase-server then firebase-server respond with "registerationToken", then at this point client should submit this token to your server, so you can send notification to that specific client using that "registerationToken"
p.s. you can read concepts at this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials

Answer (score 1):

The firebaseAdmin messaging throw a token error with the .net libraries hence i tested with Postman and works i was able to send the notifications and I see postman generates a code for Resharper library and was easy to install and use, is better to serialize the message with Json and send as parameter

```
using Firebase.Auth;
using FirebaseAdmin;
using FirebaseAdmin.Auth;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAdmin.Auth.FirebaseAuth;
using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace messaging
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            string token = "dtPMeTshqr??????????????";


            var data = new
            {
                to = token,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Nueva notificacion de prueba",
                    title = "Notificacion de prueba",
                },
                priority = "high"
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            Sendmessage(json);

        }

        private static string Sendmessage(string json)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "key=AAAAexjc2Qg:APx??????????????");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            return response.Content;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How to create a firebase token using admin SDK? I am trying to implement push notifications in asp.net MVC.